# Half pyramid with alternate coloured rows

Tags: c, xcode, colors

I apologize in advance if this isn't the place to ask but I'm struggling with an assignment. First, I have to write a C program that asks the user for a natural number 0 and prints on the screen a half pyramid formed by rows of '*' (asterisks).

I have done that already, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int x, n, rows;
   printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
   scanf("%d", &rows);
   for (x = 1; x <= rows; ++x) {
      for (n = 1; n <= x; ++n) {
         printf("* ");
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   
}
```

Next, I have to modify the above program so that it displays the rows of asterisks in RED and BLUE alternately, always starting with RED.

For this, I'm using the #include "colours.h" and colours.c when compiling, but it doesn't work in Xcode despite including it in the same folder.

But here's what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "colours.h"

int main() {
   int x, n, rows;
   printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
   scanf("%d", &rows);
   for (x = 1; x <= rows; ++x) {
       if(x-1%2 == 0)
       {
           for( n = 0; n < x+1; n++)
           {
               change_color(RED);
               printf("* ");
           }
       }
       else
       {
           for (n = 1; n <= x; ++n)
           {
               change_color(BLUE);
               printf("* ");
           }
       }
         printf("* ");
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
```

How can I use colours.c in Xcode to know wether this is correct or not?

Comment: If your compiler is giving you error messages, please include them. In the meantime the order of operations in `(x-1%2 == 0)` could be clarified.

Comment: It's even harder for us to "understand the errors" since you don't tell us what errors you get. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them (like including possible build errors, copy-pasted *as text* in full and complete).

Comment: That's not much better. "Doesn't work" really is not a good problem description. Give the exact errors or incorrect behaviours.

Comment: If the console doesn't support colours, pick another way of mimicking colours, rather than solving different things than a training course is trying to teach. Imagine you need to alternate between `x` and `o`.

Comment: Hint: The modulo operator `%` is a division operator, with the same precedence as division. And the precedence of the mathematical operators (like addition, division, etc) follows the same as in normal math. Which makes e.g. `x - 1 % 2` equal to `x - (1 % 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your code before posting it to us, I tried to run your code and multiple errors appeared.
second , use the colours.h correctly.
this is a simple explanation:

```
c_red();
printf("This text is red.\n");
c_cyan();
printf("Goodbye!"); // This text prints in cyan's color
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the same "colour" library as the OP? And what makes you sure that this is the problem the OP is having? The question is very broad and the code have other errors that could lead to the problems the OP is having.

Comment: For sure.
im adding my resources:
https://github.com/Chiqui1234/colors.h